# Scenario Outline- I am trying to add multiple values on the text box but each time its opening a new page and then getting added

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

this is the website: https://todomvc.com/examples/angular2/
This is my class :

```
public class TodoTests {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    
    //PropertyFileReader object = new PropertyFileReader();
    @Before()
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Ketaki_264\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();  
        
    }
    @Given("^Open Firefox and start application$")
    public void Open_Firefox_and_start_application() throws Throwable {
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //driver.get("https://todomvc.com/examples/angular2/");
       
    }

    @When("^User click on valid link$")
    public void User_click_on_valid_link() throws Throwable {
        //Properties property= object.getProperty();
        //driver.get(property.getProperty("browser.baseURL"));
        driver.get("https://todomvc.com/examples/angular2/");
        
       
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Then("^I should be able to get into and see Todos as a header$")
    public void I_should_be_able_to_get_into_and_see_Todos_as_a_header() throws Throwable {
        String title=driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("My Url is" + title );
        assertEquals(title, "https://todomvc.com/examples/angular2/");
        
    }
    
    @Given("^User on home page$")
    public void User_on_home_page() throws Throwable {
        User_click_on_valid_link();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @When("^Enter valid \\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"")
    public void Enter_valid_value_on_empty_text_box_and_Hit_Enter_button(final String Value ) throws Throwable {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='What needs to be done?']")).sendKeys(Value);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @Then("^Value should get added in the TODO box$")
    public void Value_should_get_added_in_the_TODO_box() throws Throwable {
       System.out.println("Hello");
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='What needs to be done?']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
       Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

My Feature file :

```
Scenario Outline: Check if user is able to enter into text box
  Given User on home page
  When Enter valid <Value> on empty text box and Hit Enter button
  Then Value should get added in the TODO box 
 
Examples:
  | Value       |
  | ket         |
  | Call        |
  | doyourworks |
```

Every time , new page is opening and then the value is getting added, instead i want it to remain on same page and the value should be getting added..

Plase can anyone tell me where i am going wrong.. I am new to this and trying to learn :)

Comment: Please add a nicely formatted version of your scenario outline to the question

Answer (score 1):

A scenario outline is a way to run the same scenario multiple times with different values. So for each row in your examples table a new instance of the scenario will be run.

If you want to add multiple values in a single scenario you need to ditch the scenario outline and write something like

```
Given ...
When I add some todo's
Then some todo's should be added
```

So you have a single step that adds multiple TODO's

Answer (score 1):

diablolist is pointing you in the right direction. A scenario outline is not the right tool. A scenario outline is basically a template of a scenario that gets executed once for each row in the examples table. Instead, add the table directly to your `When` step, but it will need a little re-phrasing:

```
When the user enters the following values:
  | Value       |
  | ket         |
  | Call        |
  | doyourworks |
```

Your step definition will receive a `DataTable` argument.

See https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#data-tables for more information.